# JQuery Ajax not updating DOM (I think)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a problem, in my page, I have a div that contains lets say two hidden fields with the value 0 and 2. I have a button that trigger an ajax query and change the div contents with the same hidden fields but with the value 1 and 2 respectively. The problem is that it seems like my javascript (using JQuery) is not aware of theses changes. When I inspect my page to see the html source code I see the values have changed but in the script when I'm doing:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    alert($("#hidden1").val());
    alert($("#hidden2").val());
});
```

It still show me the old value (0 and 2) like if the DOM hasn't been updated. Can someone help me please or tell me if it is normal and how to fix it.

Thanks for your time
Me!

Comment: Can you add the code that changes the fields

Comment: Where's the code that changes it?

Comment: where are you changing the values of hidden1 and hidden2?

Comment: If the ajax call is supposed to change the values on those fields, you need to wait until the ajax call has finished, before alerting the values of the input fields. Look into the `success(data)` property of the ajax method.

Comment: User are you sure you don't have two of each of those hidden fields ? Are you absolutely sure that you are replacing those during the ajax request ?

Comment: the code where I change the content is a little bit long... but I use the .load() method and I can see visualy that it has changed since other things are shown too and when I inspect the source code of these elements, I can see that the hidden field's value have changed and the click is not even related in this event trigger... it has it's own trigger and function so i'm pretty sure it's not a matter of waiting a certain delay.

Comment: Oh my god! Just found it... I can't believe i'm that supid :( shame on me. My page wrapper's id have the same exact name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  alert($("#hidden1").val());
  alert($("#hidden2").val());
});
```

Comment: What does `.live()` have to do with the DOM not getting updated? `.live()` ensures event listeners are bound to the selector, not to currently present elements that match the selector.

Comment: Didn't `.live()` get deprecated as well..?

Comment: Yes, it was deprecated. Old habits die hard. It was replaced with `on()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the DOM is not being updated, it's probably because your jQuery event is bound to the particular element **at the time .click() is called**. Since the DOM changed(you likely removed and added a new element of the same id), the function returns the values of the elements you discarded(because it remains bound to it even if removed from DOM).

Use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as a replacement for your [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler. This method provided by jQuery will not bind to a particular DOM element at the time it is called, but does a dynamic lookup every time a click is detected.

Comment: Actually the two are not related. My div is updated upon a certain event not related to the button click and the click is manually after the changes are done.. so why it wouldn't be updated?

Comment: So your button does not get replaced?

Comment: Then there is something else going on, perhaps make a jsFiddle or something to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: can I simulate ajax calls on jsFiddle ?? Because otherwise it would be pointless